# Get values from if/else statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, scope

If I have a series of if/else statements like this where I want to get a specific value, how would I then access that value outside of the equation? I'm having everything go through command prompt and don't have any additional classes.

```
if (shippingInput == 1)
{
    double shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 3;
}
else if (shippingInput == 2)
{
    double shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 4;
}
else
{
    double shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 5.5;
}
```

Towards the end of my code I have

```
double shippingCost = shippingAmount + surcharge;
```

but it says the name 'shippingAmount' and 'surcharge' does not exist in the current context.

Thanks for your help! I can't mark an answer yet but after declaring the statement outside of the if/else brackets and removing double from each one it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you declare a variable within a block construct such as an If statement, that variable's scope is only until the end of the block. [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx#methodscope_topic1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making new variables each time.  Declare it once like this:

```
double shippingAmount;

if (shippingInput == 1)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 3;
}
else if (shippingInput == 2)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 4;
}
else
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 5.5;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I tried doing that but then was receiving more errors. I didn't think about how I was assigning double to each shipping amount. Once I removed double from each if/else if block it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2781666 - No problem, but remember -- you were not assigning double, you were declaring (same as creating) a new variable each time.  Important distinction to understand.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize that it was like declaring a new variable every time. That definitely will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you need to define the variables outside the statements.

```
double shippingAmount;


/*some more logic*/

if (shippingInput == 1)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 3;
}
else if (shippingInput == 2)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 4;
}
else
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 5.5;
}
```

By defining the variables in your if/else statement, they only exist inside the curly brackets context and therefor are not accessible, once you have stepped out of the codeblock.

Comment: I'd recommend a word other than "disposed", which has a specific meaning in .net (related to `IDisposable`).

Comment: Righty, I have corrected the wording. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable before the statements, with default value (one from `else` part of your logic):

```
double shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 5.5;
if (shippingInput == 1)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 3;
}
else if (shippingInput == 2)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `shippingAmount` out of the if/else scope:

```
double shippingAmount = 0;

if (shippingInput == 1)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 3;
}
else if (shippingInput == 2)
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 4;
}
else
{
    shippingAmount = shippingDetails * 5.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it.

```
var shippingAmount = (shippingInput == 1) ? shippingDetails * 3 :
                     (shippingInput == 2) ? shippingDetails * 4 :
                                            shippingDetails * 5.5;
```

Comment: Please, don't actually use this sort of code in production. It's not very readable.

Comment: While perfectly valid, this might get complicated/hard to read rather fast. Plus you can only set one variable doing it this way.

Comment: @Mario in his example I don't see him setting multiple variables.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum for very simple operation like this I would always use something like this instead of wasting space.

Comment: Space shouldn't matter for source code. And this could be a minimal example to show the problem. In reality there might be different things applied or set at once. Just imagine stuff such as different shipping costs based on the same selection.

Comment: @Steve The compiler is clever enough to make both statements about as fast and about as long. Source code readability is much more important than source code length

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) like so:

```
float multiplier;

switch(shippingInput)
{
    case 1: multiplier = 3; break;
    case 2: multiplier = 4; break;
    default: multiplier = 5.5;
}

double shippingAmount = shippingDetails * multiplier;
```